# am unable to to the database using cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1

I have a cassandra db 1.21 installed on windows 2019, am unable to to the database using cqlsh

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lp9cE.png)

Able to start the cassandra db
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ae8A.png)

when i run cqslh as below am seeing cqlsh is not recognized
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CbF9.png)

All the environment variables are set,
Can anyone let me know if anything is missing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you sure cqlsh.exe is in C:\apache-cassandra-1.2.1\bin? what user do you use for trying to use cqlsh.exe, does it have permissions to access it?

Comment: i have syadmin account to connect to login to the windows server

Comment: Please add and format error/warning messages in your post instead of adding them as image links to another site.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that's an 11-year-old version of Cassandra (1.2) running on a 19-year-old JDK (1.6), on an unsupported operating system (Windows Server 2019). And trying to access that with an unsupported version of Python (2.7) adds to the problems at-hand. Just pointing this all out, because it ultimately makes what you're trying to do more difficult.

The age of the underlying libraries make this even more problematic, because there just aren't many resources available anymore to help troubleshoot issues for those software versions. However, this was pretty much my exact development environment in 2012, so I do have some thoughts (other than to just say "upgrade").

First, cqlsh probably won't run on its own on Windows the same way that that it does on Linux. If Python is properly pathed to that directory, try: `python cqlsh`

Otherwise, the standard way people used to work with Cassandra on Windows was with a [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) terminal. If I remember right, Cygwin *should* allow you to just type `cqlsh` at the prompt.

Summary:

- Try `python cqlsh`
- Run cqlsh inside of Cygwin
- Upgrade all the things! (Cassandra, JDK, Python)
- Run Cassandra on Linux (*highly* recommended)

Comment: I agree with your comments,I was able to do everything on linux

Comment: python cqlsh worked without any issues 
Can you help me out on import export issue posted here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77763127/unable-to-import-data-from-csv-to-cassandra-db-using-cqlsh