# unable to import data from CSV to Cassandra db using cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I can export the data in CSV format using the COPY command,
however, when I try to import the data am see the following error :

```
COPY loggtest.testdclog from 'G:\logtest\diagnosticlog_table.csv' with header=true;                                                                                                             
Bad Request: unable to coerce '2019-10-14 03:38:30AUS Eastern Daylight Time' to a  formatted date (long)
          Aborting import at record #0 (line 1). Previously-inserted values still present.
0 rows imported in 0.047 seconds.
```

Can you let me know if anything missing?

is there any other way to copy data from one Windows server to another Windows server

Comment: Are you trying to copy data from one windows server to another (or) from your local windows server in CSV format into the C* table. I assume the latter and will provide my answer.

Answer (score 1):

So the timestamp format is the issue here:

> Bad Request: unable to coerce '2019-10-14 03:38:30AUS Eastern Daylight Time'

Importing with CQLSH requires timestamps to be in this format:

```
2024-01-06 11:12:09.971-0600
```

In your case, you should do a search/replace in the `diagnosticlog_table.csv` file so that the times are formatted like this:

```
2019-10-14 03:38:30+1100
```

From a quick Google search, the UTC offset for Eastern Australian Daylight Time was +11. Please adjust if that's not correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what version of Cassandra (C*) you're using nor what is the step that failed.

Could you provide the below?

- Version of C*
- Exact `COPY` command and console output
- Any other `system.log` related info/error messages
- OSS C* documentation on the cassandra.apache.org is [here](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.1/cassandra/tools/cqlsh.html#copy-from)
- [more examples here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.x/cql/cql_reference/cqlshCopy.html) has more examples on the usage.

---

There is also a free open-source tool that is called **DataStax Bulk Loader (aka DSBulk)** which can seamlessly perform load/unload/count operations. Check out the below references,

These multi-part DSBulk blog series should help you get going:

- DSBulk intro - https://www.datastax.com/blog/introducing-datastax-bulk-loader
- Intro to DSBulk and Loading - https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading
- More Loading - https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-more-loading
- Common settings - https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-common-settings
- Unloading - https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-unloading
- Counting - https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-counting
  Loading from other locations - https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-examples-loading-other-locations

And you'll do it something like,

```
~/dsbulk-1.11.0/bin/dsbulk load -k loggtest -t testdclog -url 'G:\logtest\diagnosticlog_table.csv' -header false
```